# WIFI problem - it says firmware missing - Ubuntu version 12.04 desktop

Tags: 12.04, wireless, firmware, lspci

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a Broadcom BCM43XX working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-do-i-get-a-broadcom-bcm43xx-working)

The following is  the output of `lspci` from a terminal:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Host Bridge (rev b1)
00:00.1 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Memory Controller (rev b1)
00:03.0 ISA bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 LPC Bridge (rev b2)
00:03.1 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Memory Controller (rev b1)
00:03.2 SMBus: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 SMBus (rev b1)
00:03.3 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Memory Controller (rev b1)
00:03.5 Co-processor: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Co-processor (rev b1)
00:04.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 OHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev b1)
00:04.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 EHCI USB 2.0 Controller (rev b1)
00:06.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 OHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev b1)
00:06.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 EHCI USB 2.0 Controller (rev b1)
00:08.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 High Definition Audio (rev b1)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 PCI Bridge (rev b1)
00:0a.0 Ethernet controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Ethernet (rev b1)
00:0b.0 SATA controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 AHCI Controller (rev b1)
00:0c.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 PCI Express Bridge (rev b1)
00:0d.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 PCI Express Bridge (rev b1)
00:10.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 PCI Express Bridge (rev b1)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 PCI Express Bridge (rev b1)
00:16.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 PCI Express Bridge (rev b1)
00:17.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 PCI Express Bridge (rev b1)
00:18.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 PCI Express Bridge (rev b1)
01:07.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 05)
01:07.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 22)
01:07.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 12)
01:07.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev 12)
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C79 [GeForce 9400M G] (rev b1)
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple. Connect your computer to the internet via an ethernet cable. If you don't have an extra one, you can use the cable between your wireless router and your cable/DSL modem. Then, open up the program *Additional Drivers* by searching it in the dash. Select your driver from the list, and click "Activate". Supply your password, sit back, relax, let it install, and then reboot when prompted.